# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character in C#?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, encryption

I am using the following methods for encryption and decryption of request and response in WCF Web service :

```
public static string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt, string key)
        {
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

            RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
            rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;

            string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(textToDecrypt);
            byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedUrl);
            byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
            int len = pwdBytes.Length;
            if (len > keyBytes.Length)
            {
                len = keyBytes.Length;
            }
            Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
            rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
            rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
            byte[] plainText = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            return encoding.GetString(plainText);
        }


       public static string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt, string key)
        {
            RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
            rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
            byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
            int len = pwdBytes.Length;
            if (len > keyBytes.Length)
            {
                len = keyBytes.Length;
            }
            Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
            rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
            rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
            ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(transform.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length));
        }
```

By using  methods  data encrypted and decrypted  successfully. After that I encrypt JSON Object Successfully but facing issue in decryption
  I am using following data :

**for Encryption**

```
Encrypt("{\"password\":\"Password123\",\"username\":\"Jhon.Trrot\"}", "demo")
```

**for Decryption**

```
Decrypt(encString, "demo");
```

When I removed `:` and `,` it worked perfectly but with `:` and `,` getting this error:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. '.
```

Comment: OT, but `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);` is a very bad way to get a key from a string.

Comment: Could you show us the encoded input strings (generated by test keys of course)? Please edit into question (print out `textToDecrypt` at start of decoding method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to URL *encode* your base 64 output in the encryption method.